# Jquery Clickable Map : Africa only map

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm using jquery vector map (http://jqvmap.com/) TO have an interactive map. I would like to have only the Africa map. can someone Help out on this please ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source from [this](http://techslides.com/demos/mapping/7674/jqvmap.html) page, you can see how you can limit the map:

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'africa_en',
    backgroundColor: null,
    color: '#ffffff',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    selectedColor: '#666666',
    enableZoom: true,
    showTooltip: true,
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
});
```

Specifically, this line:

```
map: 'africa_en'
```

Though it looks like you may need to an external source, such as the [africa.js](http://techslides.com/demos/mapping/7674/africa.js) that it references.

Without external files, your solution may be to zoom in on Africa in the world map, as shown in a demo [here](http://techslides.com/demos/mapping/jqvmap-africa.html):

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: null,
    color: '#ffffff',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    selectedColor: '#666666',
    enableZoom: false,
    showTooltip: true,
    values: sample_data,
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    transX: -570,
    transY: -350,
    scale: 2.75
});
```

Comment: last question how can I have the country name displayed ? I just have numbers

Comment: If you are using the `africa.js` file, you'll have to change the names of the elements. For example, if you search for Algeria, at the end you'll see: `"name" : "0"`. Not sure why it works this way if they define the names anyway!